# Arris Wifi will not let me connect more than 2 devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, isp

Just got internet installed today and I cannot connect more than 2 devices at the same time. The device, is a wifi router / modem and it is an Arris DG2470. I can only connect 2 devices via wifi or 1 wifi 1 ethernet at the same time. I tried looking at router settings page but nothing popped out to me. My isp is Astound. I hope they are not limiting me to 2 devices per instance as that was not stated anywhere, when I signed up.  Any ideas?

Comment: Log into its settings page and see if somehow the NAT range or DHCP address range/pool got set to just 2 addresses. Also make sure its LAN subnet mask is 255.255.255.0, not something like 255.255.255.248.

Comment: Also, call them back and have them issue you a router that is NOT on the badmodems.com list of known-bad modems based on the crappy Intel Puma 6 chipset (your Arris DG2470 is unfortunately on the badmodem list). These modems/gateways have unfixable hardware bugs that makes them have high latency when moving lots of small packets around, which is bad for gaming and teleconferencing.

Comment: Lan ip is 192.168.0.1.  
Subnet is 255.255.255.0 DNS override is disabled. DNS relay is off and NAT mode is Bridged. UPnP is enabled. 

WAN ip is static 192.168.255.10.         
Sub is 255.255.255.0 and wan gateway is 192.168.255.1. Should I be using DHCP for the WAN config?

Comment: When I enable DHCP on the WAN settings (dynamic ip) the subnet mask becomes 255.255.248.0 